# Java-Selenium2: How to fix the below exception in java code after exporting from selenium IDE

Tags: java, selenium, exception

I am learning selenium and Java.
Trying to create a test script to book hotel, then view the itinerary and finally perform logout operation on  a test site.
After clicking "book_now" button it takes some time to load the next frame/page where the itinerary button exists.
I explicitly added "waitForFrameToLoad" command as the test case was failing on IDE stating "my_Itinerary" element not found.
After addition test case passed on IDE and when exported using junit/webdriver option,I see the below note:

```
package com.example.tests;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class CompleteBooking {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://www.adactin.com/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }
 @Test
  public void testCompleteBooking() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/HotelAppBuild2/");
    driver.findElement(By.id("username")).sendKeys("pranu86”);
    driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("test”);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("hotels"))).selectByVisibleText("Hotel Sunshine");
    driver.findElement(By.id("Submit")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("radiobutton_0")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("continue")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.id("first_name")).sendKeys("pranu");
    driver.findElement(By.id("cc_num")).sendKeys("1234567891234567");
    new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("cc_type"))).selectByVisibleText("VISA");
    driver.findElement(By.id("book_now")).click();
    // ERROR: Caught exception [ERROR: Unsupported command [waitForFrameToLoad | http://www.adactin.com/HotelAppBuild2/BookingConfirm.php | 10000]]
    // ERROR: Caught exception [Error: locator strategy either id or name must be specified explicitly.]
    driver.findElement(By.id("my_itinerary")).click();
    // ERROR: Caught exception [unknown command [clickAndWait ]]
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Click here to login again")).click();}
  }
@After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);}}

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;}}

private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;}}

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
```

How to fix this issue/Error note?  Please help

Comment: i dont find any wait command in the script above?

Comment: Yeah can you post all your code?

Comment: Please check the edited code and guide me to fix the Errors.

Comment: Can somebody please help to fix it?